# MySQL query to C# with save to XML

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, ado.net

I have the following problem:

Need to translate a query to the database MySQL (with save result in XML file) in query using the C# (ADO.Net Entity Framevork, or LINQ to SQL) with save of the result in the XML file

Query:

```
SELECT E.ID AS `ID`, E.XML_ID AS `XML_ID`, PA.VALUE AS `ART`, CONCAT_WS(' ', EC.XML_ID, EB.NAME, E.NAME) AS `FULL_NAME`, S.NAME AS `SECTION_NAME`, I.NAME AS `IBLOCK_NAME`, concat('/catalog/', I.CODE, '/', E.IBLOCK_SECTION_ID, '/', E.ID) AS `URL`
FROM b_iblock_element E
      INNER JOIN b_iblock I ON (I.ID = E.IBLOCK_ID)
      LEFT JOIN b_iblock_section_element SE ON (E.ID = SE.IBLOCK_ELEMENT_ID)
      LEFT JOIN b_iblock_section S ON (S.ID = SE.IBLOCK_SECTION_ID)
      LEFT JOIN o_product_props PA ON (PA.PRODUCT_ID=E.ID AND PA.CODE='ART')
      LEFT JOIN o_product_props PB ON (PB.PRODUCT_ID=E.ID AND PB.CODE='BRAND')
      LEFT JOIN b_iblock_element EB ON (EB.ID = PB.VALUE)
      LEFT JOIN o_product_props PC ON (PC.PRODUCT_ID=E.ID AND PC.CODE='PREFIX')
      LEFT JOIN b_iblock_element EC ON (EC.ID = PC.VALUE)
WHERE E.WF_PARENT_ELEMENT_ID is NULL 
 AND(E.ACTIVE = 'Y')
 AND (I.IBLOCK_TYPE_ID = 'catalog')
```

P.S. Yes, I have Connector/Net for MySQL

Answer (score 1):

Try to fill a DataTable and call [WriteXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.writexml%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) method.

Comment: Could you talk about this more in detail, with examples?

Comment: There are a lot of examples of how to load data into the table; for example - 'Populating a DataSet from a DataAdapter' - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bh8kx08z.aspx. You can populate DataSet or DataTable, and then call WriteXml for the storage (table or dataset).